# copy constructor not called when returning a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I want to know what's happening here:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() { std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl; }
    Test(const Test &) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
    Test(const Test &&) { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl; }
};
std::vector<Test> getTestVektor() {
    std::vector<Test> TestVektor(1);
    return TestVektor;
}
Test getTest() {
    Test TestVariable;
    return TestVariable;
}

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<Test> TestVektor = getTestVektor();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        Test TestVarible = getTest();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        std::vector<Test> TestVektor(1);
        std::vector<Test> TestVektor2 = TestVektor;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with VisualStudio 2012:

```
Constructor
Destructor

Constructor
Move
Destructor
Destructor

Constructor
Copy
Destructor
Destructor
```

One could explain the first case with copy elision. But that's contrary to the second case, where the move constructor was called.

Another explanation would be, that the std::vector in the function releases its contents and passes it to the second std::vector, so there is no call of the copy constructor. But the third case shows, that that's not the case.

So, what's happening here? Or is this just mazy compiler opitimization?

Comment: Familiar with "Named Return Value Optimization"?  (I agree it should apply in case #2 also)

Comment: Where are your copy/move assignment operators?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes. Apparent the vector's move constructor is the important point...

Comment: @xaxxon Seemingly my Compiler implicitly declares them...

Comment: @Corylus what I was getting at is you don't have print statements for them.

Comment: @xaxxon It's [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case (at worst) moves the vector (so just transfers the internal pointer, without copy/move of `Test`).

The 3rd case makes a copy of vector, you would have to do the following to move it instead of copy:

```
{
    std::vector<Test> TestVektor(1);
    std::vector<Test> TestVektor2 = std::move(TestVektor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> One could explain the first case with copy elision.

`TestVektor` was move constructed from the temporary vector that was returned from `getTestVektor`. One, both or neither of the moves may have been elided.

> But that's contrary to the second case, where the move constructor was called.

Copy/move elision is not mandatory. It could be used for both the return from `getTest` and copy initialization of `TestVarible`, but it wasn't used for one of them.

Versions of both GCC and Clang that I tested elided both.

> Another explanation would be, that the std::vector in the function releases its contents and passes it to the second std::vector

That's exactly what the move constructor of `std::vector` does.

But the third case does copy assignment, not a move construction.

In conclusion, what's happening here is mostly explained by the move constructor of `std::vector`, but the second case also shows observable (lack of) side effects from copy/move elision.

Answer (score 0):

FYI the output from clang, with -O2:

```
Constructor
Destructor

Constructor
Destructor

Constructor
Copy
Destructor
Destructor
```

Why visual studio would invoke a move in case 2 is a mystery to me. Did you disable optimisations?

Comment: Changed to /O2 and got the same ;-)